# C++: Confusion over function overloading and order of declaration

Tags: c++, function, overloading

I realize that C++ inherited many requirements from C, and one of those is that the compiler won't recognize a global function unless it has previously encountered a prototype or definition for this function.

This also effects C++ function overloading.  If there is more than one candidate for a function call, the "correct" candidate won't be included in the selection process if the compiler hasn't already seen a prototype/definition for it.

Consider:

```
void foo(int v)
{
    cout << "Int version" << endl;
}

template <class T>
void call_foo(const T& v)
{
    foo(v);
}

void foo(const std::string& v)
{
    cout << "Overload for string" << endl;
}
```

Here, a call to `call_foo(std::string("abc"))` will result in a **compiler error**, even though there is an overload of `foo` for `std::string`.  The problem is that the function template `call_foo` was defined *before* the compiler sees the overload.

However, this doesn't seem to apply to global *operator overloads*.  We regularly overload `std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const T&);` to make our custom types compatible with C++ ostreams.  The compiler selects the correct overload, regardless of where the operator overload function is defined.

For example:

```
struct Bar { };

template <class T>
void dispatch(const T& v)
{
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Bar& b)
{
    os << "Outputting Bar...";
    return os;
}
```

Here, if we call `dispatch(Bar())`, the compiler calls the correct overload and outputs `Outputting Bar...`.

So, it seems the C++ standard allows more advanced behavior when it comes to selecting candidate functions for operator overloading.

My question is, why wasn't this ability extended to regular function overloading?  I realize there is the requirement of backwards compatibility with C, but this wouldn't really have any bearing on that because as soon as you write a function overload you're not writing a C program anyway.

Comment: The second `foo` is not a specialization, it is simply another function that overloads the name foo.

Comment: I don't understand your `operator<<` example, as it has no comparison with your first example. There's no dispatch template, just various overloads.

Comment: @Gman, the point is that if a dispatch template is defined *before* an overload of `operator<<` is written, the correct overload is selected anyway when you call the dispatch template.  But this doesn't happen for regular functions.

Comment: @Channel: It does. AGain, your examples aren't comparable. If there were a generic `operator<<` then a generic dispatcher, no further overloads would be found through the dispatcher, just like your example. But there is neither a generic `operator<<` nor a generic `operator<<` dispatcher in the standard library. Adding a generic dispatcher, as your comment suggests, is only half of the equation. You're still missing a generic function for it to call.

Comment: @Gman, okay I expanded the question a bit to elaborate on what I'm talking about.  Note that the dispatch function is defined *before* the overload.  But the compiler does the correct thing anyway.  But, this only seems to work with an operator overload - rather than a regular function overload.

Comment: I edited it once again to avoid the distraction of a general templated version.  I just want to focus on overloads in general, and why it is that regular functions require a definition/prototype before the compiler will consider them as an overload resolution candidate, but the same rules don't seem to apply for operator overloads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there's no need for the compiler to see a definition when it
practices overload resolution; a declaration suffices.  Second, the
issue is a lot more complex than you seem to realize.  In your function
template `call_foo`, `foo` is a dependent name, because it is used in a
context which depends on the instantiation type.  That means that it
will be looked up twice, once at the point where the template is
defined, and a second time where the template is instantiated.  This
second lookup, however, is purely ADL; it won't find a declaration not
brought in by ADL.  In your case, the `foo` you want is in the global
namespace, but when calling it with `std::string`, the only namespace
considered by ADL is `std::`.

In your second example, `Bar` is in global namespace, so declarations in
global namespace at the point of instantiation will be considered.
(Note that if `dispatch` were not a template, it wouldn't be
considered.)